# How do I configure CakePHP to detect my development / production environments or do I just keep the config files out of version control?

Tags: cakephp, production-environment

I am a RoR developer, but I am presently working with CakePHP for a project where I cannot tweak the server. In my Rails production server, Passenger is setup to automatically use the "Production" environment, overriding the local app setup. I would like to setup my cakephp app to do the same thing. How do you usually accomplish that with CakePHP? Do you set up a domain parser, or you just keep core.php and database.php out of version control? 
Thanks in advance,
Davide

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this might be the thing you need:

[Automatically choose database connections in CakePHP](http://edwardawebb.com/programming/php-programming/cakephp/automatically-choose-database-connections-cakephp)

Briefly, override the `DATABASE_CONFIG` constructor:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG
{
    //initalize variable as null
    var $default=null;

    //set up connection details to use in Live production server
    var $prod = 
        array(
            // ...
        );

    // and details to use on your local machine for testing and development
    var $dev = 
        array(
            // ...
        );

    function __construct ()
    {       
        if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])){
            switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']){
                case 'digbiz.localhost':
                    $this->default = $this->dev;
                    break;
                case 'digbiz.example.com':
                    $this->default = $this->prod;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else // we are likely baking, use our local db
        {
            $this->default = $this->dev;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly waht I was looking for

Comment: GLad this article helped you :) please leave feedback

Comment: Link no longer works. In the future, it's a good idea to quote the important details from a link just in case this happens.

Comment: @BMitch: You are correct, it's a very good idea. I hope this is just a temporary error.

Comment: @BMitch: I've updated the answer now that Eddie's site is back online.

Answer (score 9):

It might be better to define the prod/dev in bootstrap.php. That way you can reuse the constant across the app.

bootstrap.php:

```
define('IS_PROD',(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'cubismedia.com') ? true : false);
```

database.php:

```
function __construct() {
        if (IS_PROD) {
            $this->default = $this->prod;
        } else {
            $this->default = $this->dev;
        }
    }

//development
public $dev = array(
    //db settings
);

//production
public $prod = array(
    //db settings
);
```

Comment: This is basically what I do, but I do it up a level in core.php. I set a constant there called "APPLICATION_ENV" so I can reference it elsewhere in the code and also load an environment specific config file where I define constants (config values would work too) for things like database host, api keys, etc.

Comment: which one is better? put it in bootstrap or core? pro/cons?

Answer (score 1):

You could just create an extra file that holds the single `Configure::write('debug', 0)`* directive, import that in the core.php file and keep it out of version control. Best of both worlds.

*or whatever else you need to change

Answer (score 1):

For the database, you could set up the local and production connection settings and then create the file app/app_model.php and include the line:

```
class AppModel extends Model
{
  var $useDbConfig = 'production';
}
```

Then you could create the file app/app_controller.php and parse the domains and tell it which dbconfig to use and any other core.php settings by using Configure::write.